# Field is not writeable: Task.IsDeleted Error in test class

Tags: apex, soql, tasks

I am writing a test class for an apex class which is having tasks associated with the custom object. The apex class contains the following code.

```
List<Task> taskListProd = [Select Id, Type_of_Activity__c, Subject, Type__c, CallType, lastModifiedDate, CallClassification1__c From Task where WhatId =: prod.id and isdeleted=false];
```

for covering the above code in test class I have written the code as

```
Task t1=new Task();
t1.Subject='Send Email';
t1.WhatId = prod1.id;
t1.IsDeleted = false;
insert t1;
```

but I am receiving an error as

> Field is not writeable: Task.IsDeleted

Not able to find the root cause. am I doing anything wrong here or missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've deleted the task, the field `IsDeleted` will default to `false`.  So you don't need to set this field explicitly.

Remove the line `t1.IsDeleted = false;`.